# I want to read context.xml in Tomcat in my spring Boot project. How can I do?

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

spring boot project, I wrote this into context.xml in tomcat.

`<Context>
<Parameter name="videoPath" value="C:\Users\.." override="false"/>
<Parameter name="imagepath" value="C:\Users\.." override="false"/>
</Context>`

@Autowired
 ServletContext context;

context.getInitParameter("imagepath") is returning null when using in method. Why? Should I do something else?

Comment: Linked duplicate has the answer, but you may find [a better place to put your config](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html).

Comment: setServletContext() is missing in your case. Add it and you are good to go.

Comment: It is work! thank u